# How to resolve a maven build error when a plugin (gwt-maven-plugin) descriptor fails to load?

Tags: java, maven-2, gwt

I'm attempting to start a fresh project that hopes to use GWT 1.7.1, the Google Plugin for Eclipse, and Maven 2. I inferred that the best way to do this would be to setup the project using the Mojo [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin)'s archetype from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124890/gwt-maven-plugin-unable-to-run-archetype-generated-sample-project-in-eclipse).

All was going well until I attempted a build. The archetype adds a **generateAsync** goal, and Maven is reporting that it doesn't know what that goal's default phase should be.

```
11/30/09 9:09:53 AM EST: Build errors for your-artifact-name-here; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to construct build plan for: gwt-maven-archetype-project
Id: com.crowehorwath:licensing-forms-gwt:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
task-segment: [process-test-resources]. Reason: Failed to load plugin descriptor for: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.1-SNAPSHOT:generateAsync. Cannot discover it's default phase, specified in its plugin descriptor.
```

Any ideas? Hopefully I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try version 1.1 of the gwt-maven-plugin instead of 1.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Thanks! Total oversight on my part. Changed to `<version>1.1</version>` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try running from the command line using Maven if you have not done so already.

The following jira might help as well: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-85?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel.